# Capturing Ctrl Key in full screen chart

Tags: apache-flex, keyboard, fullscreen

I am able to capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Key just fine in normal mode using `event.ctrlKey`

For some reason, the flag is not set in fullscreen.

```
protected function chart_itemClickHandler(event:ChartItemEvent):void {
  if(event.ctrlKey) {
    // do something (not executed in fullscreen mode)
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
```

Is there any trick to get this flag in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all keyboard input is disabled in fullscreen mode. This includes the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key. Adobe has done this for **security reasons**. Only the <kbd>escape</kbd> key is allowed, which closes fullscreen mode.

An example: if you would make a fullscreen application that looks exactly like a default Windows logon screen, you could trick a user into typing in his Windows credentials into your application.

I'm also afraid the short answer to your question is: there's no workaround. (Except perhaps if you would use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) and some JavaScript to put the browser in fullscreen mode instead of the Flash application.)

Comment: Right! Keyboard evets are allowed in fullscreen only in AIR apps, not Flash-Web apps.